# "I'll never allow that to happen." and "I'd never allow that to happen"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, will-would, future-constructions

"I'd never allow that to happen."  This is a phrase from a popular anime, Madoka Magika.

What is the difference between "I'll never allow that to happen." and "I'd never allow that to happen."?  I very often hear people use "would" but I still don't quite get the difference between "will" and "would".

Answer (score -1):

"I will never..." implies that it's actually up to you to allow it or not. "I would never..." implies that it's probably not up to you. But if it *was* up to you, you would never allow it.

Perhaps another example makes the difference more clear:

> I have a bicycle, and I *will* ride it to work everday.
> If I had a bicycle, I *would* ride it to work everyday (but I don't have one).

Comment: It could also mean _Whatever the circumstances might be, I would never allow it._

Comment: >>Whatever the circumstances might be, I would never allow it. <<  
Does that mean "would" is stronger than "will"?